# Замена слова в python

Tags: python

Как сделать так что если в args есть буква "я" оно заменялось на ты

```
async def process_message(self, msg):
    c, args = self.parse_message(msg)

    if not args:
        return await msg.answer(f"Используйте {self.command_example()} <текст>\n(без `<` или `>`)")

    if msg.is_multichat:
        tipo = random.choice(self.tipo)
        tochno = random.choice(self.tochno)
        users = await msg.api.messages.getChatUsers(chat_id=msg.chat_id, fields='name')
        user = random.choice(users)

        await msg.answer(f"✳ {tipo}, это @id{user['id']} ({user['first_name']} {user['last_name']}) {tochno}")

    else:
        await msg.answer("Эту команду можно использовать только в беседе.")
```

Comment: Во-первых, какой тип имеет `args`? Во-вторых, в приведённом коде переменная `args` не используется нигде, кроме проверки на истинность.

Comment: args = self.parse_message(msg) он парсит то что ввел пользователь в переменную args

Comment: То есть это строка?

Comment: Да именно так..

Comment: `args.replace('я', 'ты')`

Answer (score 0):

При условии, что args - это строка, то можно обойтись стандартными методами:

```
agrs.replace('я', 'ты ')
```

Comment: Благодарю, а если допустим несколько значений нужно сменить?

Comment: тогда может произойти такое, что  если в тексте есть какая то `я` ,то она будет заменяться на `ты` не зависимо отдельно `я` будет стоять или в каком нибудь слове

Answer (score -1):

Попробуй сделать условия `if in agrs я` и дальше пропиши замену `Я` с помощью `agrs.replace()` на `ты`